# How to see the number of topic subscribers on FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I've been trying to find a server API for looking up how many clients are subscribed to a particular topic.

On the Firebase console, if I want to send a manual (non-API) notification, I could see the estimated number of subscribers for each topic, so I'm guessing it is actually possible to retrieve those numbers by API. Is it possible?

[image: Firebase console]